# How to send notification to users in PHP

Tags: php

I am working on an auction page right now, not for publishing it into real world but only for experiment and enhancing my PHP knowledge

so basically I need a system that can notify a member where the member has been outbid by other member. I am thinking about notification like Facebook, where there is a notification center on member's dashboard. I have done researches about it but I cant find any sites that help me in building such system. I am sorry that I couldnt provide any codes for I dont know how to achieve it.

Can anybody help me please? thanks

Comment: `long-polling`, `websocket` etc

Comment: There are several methods to achieve this. My preferences are using long polling or websockets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet

Comment: I'd recommended jQuery.

Comment: @Coulton why jQuery ?

Comment: There is certainly no *need* to use jQuery. It isn't even likely to be all that helpful since, AFAIK, it doesn't have web socket helper functions.

Comment: To edit the DOM to indicate a new notification to the user.

Comment: @RichardBernards How are you going to edit the DOM using long polling or web sockets?

Comment: Actually, there is a good plugin for websockets with jQuery : [gracefulWebSockets](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-graceful-websocket/). But yeah, no need to jQuery to make it work.

Comment: @Coulton jQuery is a pure javascript library... So javascript can do all that jQuery does. Including of course manipulating the DOM

Comment: @Coulton update the DOM using vanilla javascript: `document.getElementById().innerHTML = '<div>nice</div>';` ??

Comment: I don't get what you guys have a problem with, it was a suggestion.  Long polling and DOM manipulation can be achieved elegantly jQuery... give over!  Other than suggesting technologies, this question's answer is too broad and non-specific.  jQuery is a perfectly valid suggestion.